# Remove "The current page has been customized from its template."

Tags: 2013

Nothing makes it disappeared. I tried everything in [here](http://ranaictiu-technicalblog.blogspot.com/2010/05/sharepoint-2010-current-page-has-been.html)
but nothing happened. What else should I do to hide or remove that statusbar messages.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In master page , I make displa property none for status bar

```
<div class="ms-tableRow" style="display:none">
    <div class="ms-tableCell ms-verticalAlignTop">
        <div id="notificationArea" class="ms-notif-box"></div>
        <SharePoint:AjaxDelta id="DeltaPageStatusBar" BlockElement="true" runat="server">   
            <div id="pageStatusBar"></div>
        </SharePoint:AjaxDelta>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6):

Add following script to your Page

```
<style type="text/css">
#pageStatusBar
{
    display:none!important;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    <div style="display:none">
      <div id="notificationArea" class="ms-notif-box"  ></div>
     <SharePoint:AjaxDelta id="DeltaPageStatusBar" BlockElement="true" runat="server">
     <div id="pageStatusBar" style="display:none"></div>
     </SharePoint:AjaxDelta>
   </div>
```

Similar to e.ozmen's answer. Yet, the 'ms-tablerow' div did not exist for me in the seattle.master master page. So, I created the first div and added the style=display:none.

The style I added to div with id pageStatusBar appears to not have an effect.