# monotools and sharepoint 2013 conflict

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, javascript

There is a conflict between SharePoint and monotools.js .
SharePoint tries to use the method: `Type.registerNamespace` and monotools.js register a function with the name `Type` as well. If you call the monotools before some files are loaded it causes the problems:

**Uncaught TypeError: Type.registerNamespace is not a function**

in files like `sp.ui.socialribbon` in SharePoint 2013.

Is there a workaround for this kind of conflict ?

Comment: Is below given information make sense ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to register different `namespaces` for both applications in you code.

Please check below mentioned links for the reference.

[What are the Type.registerNamespace advantages over standard JavaScript methods?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/167168/what-are-the-type-registernamespace-advantages-over-standard-javascript-methods)

[CSR + MDS, where are my globals going?? (and I want them back!)](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/174447/csr-mds-where-are-my-globals-going-and-i-want-them-back/174475#174475)

Comment: Hi @Hardik, thanks for your answer. I understand there is a conflict on the namespace. Sorry if I didn't explain that part, but I have two big frameworks that I would like to change them as litle as possible. In one side many sharepoint js files that uses this namespace and in other side one big file from monotools that uses the same namespace. this.Type, I would like to know more specifically if the mono tools have a way to overcome this conflict easier, like it has with jQuery for example. It identifies if the $ is already used, if it is, it will use a different sign.

Comment: I didn't find another way more elegant them changing the Type var and it's usage from the monotools-core.js file to TypeMonotools. It took me time, since the file is more than 1k lines of code, but it worked out.

Comment: The answer Hardik gives points to some of my ramblings which are not a solution to your problem (so should not be marked as correct answer). As you identified yourself its a ``Type`` Namespace conflict between the 2 libraries, and your less then elegant solution is your only escape I am afraid. You can answer your own question and mark it as the correct answer

Comment: @DannyEngelmanNVP thanks for your comment, I even found a better way to do it (less work). If I have the minified version of the mootools file, the changes on the variable name will be only in 3 places.

Answer (score 0):

I took the minified version of the mootools file and changed it in only 3 places, instead of many, like on the not minified version. Not an elegant solution, but I couldn't find a better way.